# How to add UITableViewCell from storyboard to programmatically created UITableView object?

Tags: ios, objective-c

In my iOS app, I have tab bar with two tabs as shown below. For each tab I have created UITableView object programmatically.
[image]

I created tab bar using collection view. Next I added UITableViewCell to my view controller from storyboard.

[image]

So I got following View.

[image]

But now when I run my app I can't see the UItableviewcell. Where I am making mistake I don't get. Please help.

Below is my code.

```
#import "TicketsViewController.h"
#import "TabBarCollectionViewCell.h"
#import "TicketTableViewCell.h"
#import "Constants.h"

@interface TicketsViewController () <UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UICollectionView *tabBarCollectionView;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UICollectionViewFlowLayout *tabBarCollViewFlowLayout;
@property (weak, nonatomic) NSIndexPath *prevSelecedIndexPath;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *tabBarItemNamesArray;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *parentViewForTableViews;
@property (weak, nonatomic) UIView *previousView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *tabRespectiveTableViewsArray;

@end

@implementation TicketsViewController

#pragma mark - lazy instantiation

- (NSArray *)tabBarItemNamesArray {
    if (!_tabBarItemNamesArray)
        _tabBarItemNamesArray = @[@"All Tickets", @"Resolved Tickets"];

    return _tabBarItemNamesArray;
}

- (NSMutableArray *)tabRespectiveTableViewsArray {
    if (!_tabRespectiveTableViewsArray)
        _tabRespectiveTableViewsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:@[(id)[NSNull null], (id)[NSNull null]]];

    return _tabRespectiveTableViewsArray;
}

#pragma mark - life cycle

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.view layoutIfNeeded];

    [self tabBarItemNamesArray];
    [self tabRespectiveTableViewsArray];

    _tabBarCollectionView.delegate = self;
    _tabBarCollectionView.dataSource = self;
    _previousView = nil;

    _tabBarCollViewFlowLayout.itemSize = CGSizeMake(ceilf(_tabBarCollectionView.frame.size.width / 2), _tabBarCollViewFlowLayout.itemSize.height);

    _prevSelecedIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:0 inSection:0];
    [_tabBarCollectionView selectItemAtIndexPath:_prevSelecedIndexPath animated:NO scrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionNone];
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}

- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
}

#pragma mark - collection view

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return _tabBarItemNamesArray.count;
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    TabBarCollectionViewCell *tabBarCollectionViewCell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"TabBarCollectionViewCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    tabBarCollectionViewCell.tabView.tabTitle = [_tabBarItemNamesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    if ([_tabRespectiveTableViewsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] == (id)[NSNull null]) {
        UITableView *tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:_parentViewForTableViews.bounds style:UITableViewStylePlain];
        [tableView registerClass:[TicketTableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"TicketTableViewCell"];

        tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
        tableView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = YES;
        tableView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
        tableView.scrollEnabled = YES;
        tableView.pagingEnabled = NO;
        tableView.bounces = YES;
        tableView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
        tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

        tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
        [_parentViewForTableViews addSubview:tableView];
        [_tabRespectiveTableViewsArray replaceObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row withObject:tableView];

        [_parentViewForTableViews addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[v0]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:@{@"v0" : tableView}]];

        if (_previousView == nil) {
            [_parentViewForTableViews addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:tableView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:_parentViewForTableViews attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading multiplier:1.0f constant:0.0f]];
            _previousView = tableView;
        }
        else {
            [_parentViewForTableViews addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:tableView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:_previousView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing multiplier:1.0f constant:0.0f]];
        }

        [_parentViewForTableViews addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:tableView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:_parentViewForTableViews attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth multiplier:1.0f constant:0.0f]];

        tableView.dataSource = self;
        tableView.delegate = self;
    }

    return tabBarCollectionViewCell;
}

- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView willDisplayCell:(UICollectionViewCell *)cell forItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    ((TabBarCollectionViewCell *)cell).tabView.tabSelected = cell.isSelected;

}

- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (_prevSelecedIndexPath)
        ((TabBarCollectionViewCell *)[collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:_prevSelecedIndexPath]).tabView.tabSelected = NO;
    ((TabBarCollectionViewCell *)[collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath]).tabView.tabSelected = YES;
    _prevSelecedIndexPath = indexPath;

    [collectionView scrollToItemAtIndexPath:indexPath atScrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionCenteredHorizontally animated:YES];
    [((UITableView *)[_tabRespectiveTableViewsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]) reloadData];
}

- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didHighlightItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    ((TabBarCollectionViewCell *)[collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath]).tabView.tabHighlighted = YES;
}

- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didUnhighlightItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    ((TabBarCollectionViewCell *)[collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath]).tabView.tabHighlighted = NO;
}

#pragma mark - table view

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 5;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    TicketTableViewCell *ticketTableViewCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"TicketTableViewCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    ticketTableViewCell.labelTime.text = @"02:45 PM";

    return ticketTableViewCell;
}

#pragma mark - button actions

- (IBAction)buttonOpenDrawerAction:(id)sender {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:SHOW_LEFT_DRAWER object:self];
}

@end
```

Comment: You have to write tableview delgate and datasource methods in collectionViewcell.

Comment: @Poles - please check code. I already done this

Comment: Not getting actually, question is not properly clear, pls specify where you have tableview and at which portion you have collectionview. And try to post complete UI image.

Comment: @the_dahiya_boy - I updated screens. please have a look

Comment: @Sanket : No its not. Its in the same viewcontroller.

Comment: @poles - please see updated UI. UITableView is not part of UICollectionViewCell. Its simple. In above UI, I have one UIView which is in Yellow Color. Its my parent view. On that view I added two UITableViews (because there are two tabs) as subview. tab bar is collection view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code work is almost right, but for better coding style follow :

1. As per I getting your `UITableView` is in `UICollectionViewCell`, so do coding to the hierarchy for your view i.e. do `UITableView` code in the `UICollectionViewCell` file. Bind the `UITableView` `delegate` \ `datasouce`with the `UICollectionViewCell` file and bind `UICollectionView` `delegate` \ `datasouce`with the `UIViewController`. It makes you easy to manage all your components.
2. Whenever you are giving constraints to any component you have to activate that constraint too, now I not see any constraint activation code or may be my eyes missed it.
3. As per your screen shot of UI, I don't think you need to take two `UITableView` each for **All Tickets** and **Resolved Tickets** because at a particular time user either select **All Tickets** or  **Resolved Tickets**. So take one `UITableView` and use `reload tableview` property and change the table data.
4. And you have done half work with the `storyboard` and I don't think you need to create `UITableView` programatically because your `UITableView` not gonna change at run time, just change its data.

> Edit

**How to show data with scroll effect on UI.**

Upto your header option selection is correct.

1. For your lower yellow view take additional `UIcollectionView`
2. Set scrolling property of `UIcollectionView` to horizontal only.
3. Create a `UIcollectionViewcell`, and add `UITableView` in it.
4. Your `UIcollectionViewcell` have size of your yellow view.
5. To maintain the `UIcollectionViewcell` height, you have to calculate its inner `tableView` height and and resize  `UIcollectionViewcell` height by using `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` `sizeForItemAtIndexPath;` method.
6. Use paging in `collectionView` to get better drag effect and update your data properly as per your requirement.
7. To manage multiple collection in single class use below code in `cellforItem`

   `if(collectionView == tabCollectionView ){
   // do code here for the tab collection
   }
   else{
   // do code here for the data collectionView
   }`

Comment: For point 1 - No. I created my UITableView is programmatically. Its not the part of UICollectionViewCell. UITableView is added as subview to that Yellow view.

Comment: For point 2 - as far as constraints are concerned, see tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
        [_parentViewForTableViews addSubview:tableView];
        [_tabRespectiveTableViewsArray replaceObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row withObject:tableView]; in cellForItemAtIndexPath. _parentViewForTableViews is my view which you can see in Yellow color

Comment: If your tableview is not part of the collection then why your are initializing the tableview in the collection view. You can give load data in `CellForItem` methos

Comment: For point 3 & 4 - when you open Youtube app in android, You can see for each tab there is different table view. Want to create similar effect here. Yes you are right that I can do work with single table view. But what if I have to see the contents of table view from next tab when you draging from tab 1 to tab 2?

Comment: I am initializing table view inside collection view because I have to create two different table views corresponding to each tab. And I have two tabs only. That two tabs I can access in cellForItemAtIndexPath. So I am only initializing and adding them as subview to parent view here.

Comment: Describe actually what you are creating and what is your approach, according to that you get answers.

Comment: Your approach not gonna work, because your tableview is not in collectionView and your initialising the tableView in collectionview. We have to find new approach

Comment: If my collection view has 2 items, and for these two items, if I want to create two corresponding UITableViews, then I have to create them inside cellForItemAtIndexPath. next I added them as subview in parent view (Yello view). So I created this way. What you think? If you have better approach please tell me. I will try

Comment: Yes now it seems to be acceptable for me. Ok I will make changes as per your suggestion. Let you know as early as possible. Thanks for you efforts in answering me

Answer (score 0):

Try this in cell for row at indexPath.

```
   TicketTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
            if (cell == nil)
            {
                cell = [[TicketTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
                NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"TicketTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
                cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        Please follow the below steps  
        1. Create two array. one array will contain the data for all tickets arrAllTickets and another will contain the data for resolved tickets arrResolved  
        2. Drag one table view below two button and give IBOutlet (tblTickets) and delegate and datasource to the your controller  
        3. Drag one tableview cell and give its identifier name for ex : TicketCell  
        4. Create the custom UITableviewCell class TicketCell.h and TicketCell.m file and assign it Cell created in 3rd step.
        5. Place required control from story board to cell as per your design and give outlet to it in TicketCell.h  
        6. In your controller class in UITableView Delegate method cellForRowAtIndexPath write down below code to place the cell to tableview.

        -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
        {
            TicketCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"TicketCell"];
     Ticket *objTicket=(isAllTicketsSelected)?[arrAllTickets objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]:[arrResolved objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [cell.imgProfile sd_setImageWithURL:objTicket.profilePictureURL placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"defaultlist"]];
        [cell.lblName setText:[objTicket fullName]];
         return cell;
        } 

7. Now take one bool variable isAllTicketsSelected. make isAllTicketsSelected=true when user tap on all tickets isAllTicketsSelected= false when user tap on resolved tickets. after that reload the tableview.

isAllTicketsSelected = true
[tblTicket reloadData];
```

Comment: Thanks for posting answer. Basically tou are telling to create single UITableView that load data depending on which tab is selected. But suppose you are on tab 1 and you have to go to tab 2 using PanGestureRecognizer. So while panning from tab 1 to tab 2, consider you are in between of screen and if you want to see data of table view from tab 2. For this approach using single table view will not be the solution

Comment: You can see this effect in android youtube app while panning from one tab to other

Comment: in this case you can use Horizontal UIcollectionView  with cell. each cell has one tableview. Set paging enabled property to YES to have effect without using gesture.